# When will my Mac (15inch MacBook Pro Mid 2012 ) become a vintage product?

Tags: macbook-pro

When will my Mac (15inch MacBook Pro Mid 2012 ) become a vintage product?

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201624

Comment: The link in your post answers the question.

Comment: Most Apple products become vintage at the exact moment you finalize the sale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, based in part on information in the linked support article in your question the **vintage** designation is a 5 to 7 year window, so the two Mid 2012 15" MacBook Pro models **vintage** windows are shown below:

- The MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012) was discontinued in October 2013. So October 2018 would be the start of the 5 year window, with October 2020 being the 7 year window.
- The MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2012) was discontinued in Feburary 2013. So Feburary 2018 would be the start of the 5 year window, with Feburary 2020 being the 7 year window.

That said, if you live in Turkey, California or France, make note of what it said in the article, quoted below.

From [Vintage and obsolete products](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624):

> **Vintage products** are those that have not been manufactured for more than 5 and less than 7 years ago. Apple has discontinued hardware
>   service for vintage products with the following exceptions:
>
> - Mac products purchased in the country of Turkey. Owners of vintage Mac products may obtain service and parts from [Apple service
>     providers](http://www.apple.com/buy/locator/service/) within the country of Turkey.
> - Products purchased in the state of California, United States, as required by statute
>
>   - Owners of vintage Mac products may obtain service and parts from [Apple service providers](http://www.apple.com/buy/locator/service/) within the state of California, United
>       States.
>   - Owners of vintage iPod products in the state of California may obtain service from Apple Retail Stores or by contacting AppleCare at
>       1-800-APL-CARE.
>   - Owners of vintage iPhone products in the state of California may obtain service from Apple Retail Stores or by contacting AppleCare at
>       1-800-APL-CARE. For products purchased in France, see [Statutory
>       Warranties of Seller and Spare Parts](http://images.apple.com/fr/legal/statutory-warranty/France_Statutory_Warranty.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The window for vintage Mac is at the shortest - 5 years from the date when Apple stops selling that model at retail in the country.

Sometimes there is more time, sometimes it's 5 years to the day. If you can establish the end date for your model in your country, you should have a good estimate by adding 5 to the year.