# When will my Mac (13inch MacBook Pro Mid 2013) become a un serviceable product in California?

Tags: applecare

When will products purchased in California become un-serviceable?  [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257251/when-will-my-mac-15inch-macbook-pro-mid-2012-become-a-vintage-product?s=1%7C117.0483) answers the question in places for most cases.

According to their warranty

> Products purchased in the state of California, United States, as
>   required by statute

[source](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201624)

So it appears that items are serviced and are repaired longer in California yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Residents of California can obtain service and or parts for up to 7 years under the [Song Beverly Consumer Warranty Act](https://www.caconsumeradvocate.com/sites/www.caconsumeradvocate.com/files/base-image/Song-Beverly-Consumer-Warranty-Act-CA.pdf).

First, what Apple terms "vintage" and "obsolete" are not in anyway bound legally to what California law provides for.  For the record, Song-Beverly provides for manufacturers making parts available for up to 7 years; Apple can, in it's discretion, make "Vintage" in 8 years.

Secondly, the law only allows for replacement parts and service information be made available.

> Every  manufacturer making an express warranty with respect to an
>   electronic or  appliance product described in subdivision (h), (i),
>   (j), or (k) of Section 9801 of the  Business and Professions Code,
>   with a wholesale price to the retailer of one hundred  dollars ($ 100)
>   or more, shall make available to service and repair facilities
>   sufficient  service literature and functional parts to effect the
>   repair of a product for at least seven  years after the date a product
>   model or type was manufactured, regardless of whether the seven
>   - year period exceeds the warranty period for the product

To put this in layman's terms, see:  [Sold a defective electronic device? California Law Protects You](https://www.lemoncarsrus.com/Articles/Sold-a-defective-electronic-device-California-Law-Protects-You.shtml)

> To be clear, the law does not force manufacturers to replace an
>   electronic device that no longer works. Instead, the law requires
>   expressly warranted electronic goods to have replacement parts
>   available to consumers and service information available that allows
>   enough information for repairs.

What's most important here, is the **context** of that warranty point you brought up:

> Products purchased in the state of California, United States, as
>   required by statute.
>
> - **Owners of vintage Mac products may obtain service and parts from Apple service providers within the state of California, United States.**

(emphasis mine)

#### TL;DR

The [Song Beverly Consumer Warranty Act](https://www.caconsumeradvocate.com/sites/www.caconsumeradvocate.com/files/base-image/Song-Beverly-Consumer-Warranty-Act-CA.pdf) says that the manufacturer (Apple) must make available parts and service information for up to 7 years on your electronic device (MacBook) that was purchased in the state of California.  **This doesn't extend the warranty to 7 years.**

Comment: Does the time have to be purchased there or just a resident there

Comment: It products *purchased* in the state of CA which implies you'll need to show proof of purchase and that you don't need to be a resident.