# Where can I find original MacBook Pro batteries?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, ssd, battery, charging

I have a 2011 13" MacBook Pro. I have replaced the battery once, replaced the charger two times (because it wore off/tore up). I have replaced the original drive with an SSD and pumped up the RAM so my MacBook runs pretty much like new with Sierra (upgraded).

Now I am not taking chances on off-brand batteries because:

1. they can potentially damage/brick my laptop (my replacement battery had swollen after an year).
2. replaced batteries do not fully hold the charge and have much smaller life times.
3. because my laptop is showing no sign of slowing down, I would rather replace the battery with the original so I can use it for another 5 years or so.

The problem is I can't find original the MacBook Pro battery for a 2011 laptop. I may visit a store to find out but is there a away I can order an original MacBook Pro 2011 13" battery online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple don't sell batteries as spare parts to customers, and the Unibody MBP's battery is not 'user-serviceable'. Hence the funny tri-cornered screw heads. Anything you find on a third-party retailer's site is likely to be 'grey', even if claimed to be Apple-branded.

*(Having said that, I have bought several of such batteries for Unibody MBPs and they have worked well with no problems.)*

If you take your MBP to an Apple Store, you should be able to get it replaced, but obviously Apple will charge you 'some money' for this.

Comment: But Apple does not sell batteries for 2011 Macbook Pro's as spare parts. I confirmed from store. Not sure if they will fix it, I didn't ask for it. Got a relacment battery from Amazon and this time is working fantastic.

Comment: @mac_user My local Apple Store confirmed to me that they will repair any Mac that they can get parts for, even if it's beyond the 5 year mark. Those Unibody MBPs use the same batteries as the 2012 MBP, which Apple sold until 2016.

Comment: So the question is will they repair 2011 MacBook Pro as they do not have parts for it. The answer seems clearly no.

Comment: They won't SELL you a battery: I wrote that in my original answer. You'll have to ask if they will still replace it for you. That remains clearly unknown until asked. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several posts already that address the questions you ask:

- [When will my Mac (13inch MacBook Pro Mid 2013) become a un serviceable product in California?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/329506/when-will-my-mac-13inch-macbook-pro-mid-2013-become-a-un-serviceable-product-i/329510#329510)
- [Quality factors relevant for getting a replacement battery (MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012))](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259458/quality-factors-relevant-for-getting-a-replacement-battery-macbook-pro-13-inch/259469#259469)

Contrary to popular belief, Apple *doesn't* make batteries.  Apple OEM's (licenses) their battery manufacturing to a supplier that stamps an Apple logo on them.  These same manufacturers will sell replacement batteries without the logo.

Like with everything else, quality matters.  Battery manufacturers with a good history and a generous warranty have few, if any issues.

With very rare exceptions, Apple doesn't make available parts for vintage hardware (between 5 and less than 7 years). You're 2011 is 8 years so it's highly unlikely you'll get a genuine battery (or new replacement parts for that matter) from Apple.

Comment: It's the same battery as in the 2012 MBP, which sold up until 2016, so Apple should still have the part in stock. Whether they will replace it is another metter, of course.

Comment: @benwiggy - what Apple chooses to (not) make available regardless of the year used is Apple's policy and not something anyone can really debate.

Comment: Not sure of your point. Your answer said that the parts would be "highly unlikely"; I'm suggesting it's a bit more likely, and worth actually going to the Store to check. Did I do wrong?

Comment: @benwiggy  - No, you didn't do anything wrong.  I use the term "highly unlikely" because I can't speak to what individual Apple stores have in stock in terms of parts.  In the first link, there are links to Apple's vintage product page where they pretty much discontinue hardware support after 5 years unless required to do so by law.  Even if the law extends that period, it's only for the jurisdiction of that law (see the answer re: California).  In other words, just because they technically have the part does it mean you can get the store to replace it for you.